# Invoke-AzVMRunCommand - Best practice for error handling?

Tags: azure, powershell, error-handling, try-catch

i want to rollout multiple scripts on azure vms. 
I use the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand.

What is the best practice to implement a good error handling?

Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` is suppose to be running script on the OS level.

The only error handling you can really do on it `erroraction` and `errorvariable`, if the `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` errors out.

If the script itself errors, the run command will not have any information on that.

Comment: This is not correct. Invoke-AzVMRunCommand return a PSRunCommandResult.($output)
So in the result there are some result informations. I can find Error Stream informations in the $output.value.[2].Message variable. But it seems the variable is character limited. i think this is a way to to error handling, but not the best practice.

Comment: You will get a message in there if the script or command you ran on the OS level has a output.  But you cannot use that to error check or control the `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand`